# Sqoop not exporting all records from HDFS to MySQL

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I am currently learning Hadoop. I was practising how to export data from HDFS to MySQL using Sqoop, when I noticed that Sqoop is not exporting all the records from the HDFS file to MySQL. The HDFS file has a total of 296 records(all distinct) whereas the records in the MySQL table shows only 227 records. The table in MySQL has 3 columns-> job_title varchar(50) primary key, success_rate decimal(5,2), petition_count int. The sqoop export command used is:

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/h1b2 --username root --password 'abcd' --table h1bfinal --export-dir /h1b/queries/pigqueries/Q_010/p* --update-mode allowinsert --update-key job_title --input-fields-terminated-by '\t';
```

[Message shown after mapping is done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXMOL.png)

But it runs perfectly if I remove the "--update-mode allowinsert" command(but it doesn't insert records in MySQL table if I do it this way).

Comment: Go to your Resource Manager UI (see link at 17:14:48) and check the logs of your  MapReduce job. Most likely you have problems with you update key

Comment: @Alex You were right. I checked the logs and found out I had error at line 24 which stated that my record was too long for the varchar limit I had specified, silly me. Nevertheless, my error is resolved and thanks for the help.